# valgrind reports uninitialised value in sqlite3_step and sqlite3_prepare_v2

Tags: c++, sqlite, valgrind, initialization

Valgrind reports uninitialised value error about the sqlite3_prepare_v2 and sqlite3_step in the wrapper's following two methods.:

execQuery:

```
bool
CSQLiteDB::execQuery(const char* szSQL,CSQLiteQuery& sqlite_query_out, string* error  /*=NULL*/)
{
    if(!checkDB()){
        return false;
    }

    //HERE IS THE ESSENCE
    sqlite3_stmt* pVM = NULL;
    if(!compile(szSQL,&pVM,error)) 
    {
        return false;
    }
    int nRet = sqlite3_step(pVM); //Here is the second call with uninitialised value.
    //HERE IS THE END OF THE ESSENCE        

    if (nRet == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        sqlite_query_out = CSQLiteQuery(mpDB, pVM, true/*eof*/);
        return true;
    }
    else if (nRet == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        // at least 1 row
        sqlite_query_out = CSQLiteQuery(mpDB, pVM, false/*eof*/);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        nRet = sqlite3_finalize(pVM);
        if(error)
            *error= sqlite3_errmsg(mpDB);
        return false;
    }
}
```

compile (called from execQuery)

```
bool
CSQLiteDB::compile(const char* szSQL,sqlite3_stmt** pVM, string* error  /*=NULL*/)
{
    checkDB();
    const char* szTail = 0;
    int nRet = sqlite3_prepare_v2(mpDB, szSQL, -1, pVM, &szTail); //Here is the first call with uninitialized error.
    if (nRet != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if(error)
            *error = sqlite3_errmsg(mpDB);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

What can be wrong? In sqlite3_prepare_v2 pVM is an output value. And the pVM int sqlite3_step cannot be unitialised, because of sqlite3_prepare_v2.

Comment: Does valgrind complain about a line of code inside the SQLite call? or that your code is at fault?  Sometimes valgrind false positives and can be ignored...

Comment: There are many deeper line in the Valgrind stacktrace in this failure message with ... sqlite3VdbeExec ... sqlite3Step ... sqlite3_step. Unfortunetly my developer pc is not here for the weekend. I don't know than can I ignore the failure or not.

Answer (score 0):

The fault was my: There was SQL syntax error in a generated INSERT query. I don't know why sqlite didn't told me the syntax error, but after the redesign of INSERT generator method, there are no more unitialised value problem was reported by valgrind.
I hope this message can be useful for someone with the same problem.